# Recycler View not displayed in Android Fetched Data from API. java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently working on a college project - Virtual Stock Market where firstly I want to display stock data - Symbol and Open.
I have used Volley library.
I had previously tried converting Json to java objects using Gson but was not able to do it. So tried using different approach by referring to videos.
When I tried running the code, its running fine! But not showing the data in recycler view.

Recyclerview --> list

User is a class where all the Json data is converted into java objects
I am not understanding what the error is! Please let me know what is the issue in the code.
I have added Internet Permission as well.

public class buysell extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RecyclerView list;
ArrayList<User> data;
buysellAdapter adapter;
private static final String URL = "https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/AAPL/2020-10-14?adjusted=true&apiKey=zvaiVpsolnyLhURxiDoIpDnKsxJfgpKn";
 //c49bo82ad3ieskgqretg
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buysell);

    list = findViewById(R.id.list);
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new buysellAdapter(data,this);
    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    getStockData();



}

private void getStockData(){
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = response.getJSONObject("status");
                for(int i=0; i<jsonObj.length();i++){
                    JSONObject dataobj = jsonObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
                    String symbol = dataobj.getString("symbol");
                    Integer price = dataobj.getInt("open");

                    data.add(new User(symbol,price));

                }

            }catch (JSONException e){
                Log.d("tag","Error"+e);
            }

        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("tag","Error Occurred!");

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

}

Adapter:-

public class buysellAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<buysellAdapter.viewHolder>{

```
private ArrayList<User> data;
private Context context;
public buysellAdapter(ArrayList<User> data, Context context){
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_view,parent,false);
    return new buysellAdapter.viewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.sym.setText(data.get(position).getSymbol());
    holder.price.setText(data.get(position).getOpen());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return data.size();
}

public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView sym,price;

    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        sym = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sym);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    }


}
```

}

User class:-

public class User {

```
private Double afterHours;

private Double close;

private String from;

private Double high;

private Double low;

private Integer open;

private Double preMarket;

private String status;

private String symbol;

private Integer volume;

public User(String symbol,Integer open){
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.open = open;
}

public Double getAfterHours() {
    return afterHours;
}

public void setAfterHours(Double afterHours) {
    this.afterHours = afterHours;
}

public Double getClose() {
    return close;
}

public void setClose(Double close) {
    this.close = close;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public Double getHigh() {
    return high;
}

public void setHigh(Double high) {
    this.high = high;
}

public Double getLow() {
    return low;
}

public void setLow(Double low) {
    this.low = low;
}

public int getOpen() {
    return open;
}

public void setOpen(Integer open) {
    this.open = open;
}

public Double getPreMarket() {
    return preMarket;
}

public void setPreMarket(Double preMarket) {
    this.preMarket = preMarket;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public Integer getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

public void setVolume(Integer volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
}
```

}

Logcat Error:-

> 08-20 21:46:49.765 4893-4893/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid pid is 4893
> 08-20 21:46:49.765 4893-4893/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid value is tualstockmarket
> 08-20 21:46:50.120 4893-4935/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
> 08-20 21:46:56.915 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f945d4c88 arg=0x0
> 08-20 21:46:56.915 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA

In Verbose:-

> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 info_callback ignored
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 info_callback where=0x20 ret=1
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 handshake done in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 info_callback completed
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=1
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 SSL_connect:ok exit in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 info_callback ignored
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=1
> 08-20 21:46:57.278 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL
> 08-20 21:46:57.279 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket I/System.out: gba_cipher_suite:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> 08-20 21:46:57.281 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket I/System.out: [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0
> 08-20 21:46:57.281 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
> 08-20 21:46:57.281 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
> 08-20 21:46:57.281 4893-5299/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fb088c680 sslWrite buf=0x7f8b799800 len=240 write_timeout_millis=0
> 08-20 21:46:57.570 4893-4893/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/tag: Errororg.json.JSONException: Value OK at status of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
> 08-20 21:46:58.221 4893-4935/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 8529
> 08-20 21:49:02.037 4893-4954/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket D/InputMethodManager: receive service's setActive call, active:false
> 08-20 21:49:02.037 4893-4893/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket I/InputMethodManager: handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE false, was true
> 08-20 21:49:02.041 4893-4893/com.androidp.virtualstockmarket V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{2216c645 VFED.... .F...... 0,0-720,1244 #7f0800cd app:id/list} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3efaff7c controlFlags=#100

Comment: The response you are getting is not an array. Its an JSONObject.
So below line will throw error.
     JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("status");

Comment: What is the solution then ? Should I replace JSONArray with JSONObject?

Comment: You have to change the response of the url, as you require array inside recyclerview.

Comment: please post  your basic json structure because, here the "status" is what ?? Is it jsonArray or JsonObject ?

Answer (score 0):

Read response as JSONObject, because you are getting a josn object and trying to parse it as JsonArray that's wrong. Just parse as json object.

```
void getStockData(){
   String myUrl = "https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/AAPL/2020-10-14?adjusted=true&apiKey=zvaiVpsolnyLhURxiDoIpDnKsxJfgpKn";
    StringRequest myRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, myUrl,
            response -> {
                try{
                    //Create a JSON object containing information from the API.
                    JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String status = myJsonObject.getString("status");
                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                        String symbol = myJsonObject.getString("symbol");
                        int open = myJsonObject.getInt("open");
                        Log.e("VolleyResponse","symbol "+symbol+", open "+open);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            },
            volleyError -> {
            Log.e("VolleyResponse","volleyError "+volleyError.getMessage());
            }

    );

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(myRequest);
}
```

Comment: Still Getting an error   --> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Added the changes done by me in the code above.

Comment: Please let me know the solution ! I am trying from over 2 weeks still nothing is working

Comment: @ShreeyaDhole I have added the working method for you. check the updated answer above. You can directly copy and paste in your code.

Comment: @ShreeyaDhole Is that solve your problem? You can upvote/accept this answer in case your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Will try it soon .. Due to some technical issue was not able to continue ..